# Lifting idempotents and projective coverings --- reference request

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, projective-modules

Let $R$ be a (non-commutative, unital) ring with Jacobson radical $J$, write $\overline{R}=R/J$ and denote the quotient map $R\to \overline{R}$ by $a\mapsto \overline{a}$.

It is easy to see that if an idempotent $\epsilon \in\overline{R}$ can be lifted to an idempotent $e\in R$ (that is, $\overline{e}=\epsilon$), then the quotient map $eR\to   \epsilon \overline{R}$ is a projective covering of right $R$-modules.

**I am looking for a reference** to the converse to this fact, namely, if  $\epsilon \in\overline{R}$ is an idempotent  such that $\epsilon \overline{R}$ admits a projective covering as an $R$-module, then $\epsilon$ can be lifted to an idempotent in $R$.

While this seems like a standard fact about projective coverings, I  was unable to find it in relevant textbooks I checked (e.g. Lam's *A first course in noncommutative rings* and Rowen's *Ring Theory*). Rather, related statements are shown, usually with the purpose of proving that $R$ is semiperfect (i.e. all f.g. modules have projective coverings) if and only if $R$ is semilocal and $J$ is idempotent lifting.

Please note that  **I know how to prove it** and I am only asking for a reference. One possible proof is by using the projective covering to show that   *some* idempotent generator of $\epsilon \overline{R}$ can be lifted to an idempotent   $e_1\in R$, and then proving that $\overline{e_1}$ and $\epsilon$ are conjugate in $\overline{R}$.

Comment: I know you mentioned looking at Rowen:  did you see Lemma 2.8.36 in Volume 1?  I'm not entirely sure it can be interpreted as what you ask for, but I figured I'd draw your attention to it.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. I am aware of this lemma. One can derive from it the existence of an idempotent $e\in R$ with $\overline{eR}=\epsilon \overline{R}$, but it does not imply that $\epsilon$ itself can be lifted without further argument.